# JavaFX - method that waits for user input

Tags: java, javafx, input

I am writing a simple text game and I've dacided to move from displaying
in cmd to displaying in a custom window, that constists of one TextArea used
for output and user input. So I need a method that waits for the String that
user writes and then returns it.
In Swing i would do something like this (in a Window class):

```
public String nextToken() {
    synchronized (nextToken) {
        while (nextToken.isEmpty())
            try {
                nextToken.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                print(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        String tmp = nextToken.remove(0);
        lastToken = text.getText();
        newLine();
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

And the ActionListener for hitting enter:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            synchronized (nextToken) {
                nextToken.add(text.getText().substring(lastToken.length(), text.getText().length()));
                nextToken.notify();
            } }; };
```

But when I create a Window using JavaFX and then try to use this method the window freezes.
What to do so that the window would display correctly and would wait for user input?
I'd be thankful for any advice

Comment: What thread is `nextToken()` method running on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're waiting for input on the main thread, which will block it thus your window freezes. Try putting the waiting code (`nextToken` method) in a separate thread.